# How to select an element directly after an element with id

Tags: javascript, html, plist

I have this html:

```
<key id="myId" class="ignoreTheClass"></key>
<string>MyText</string>
```

I am aiming to be able to change the label element in some way (e.g - changing colour, edit text, etc.) without having to add an attribute to it, but I would like to do so in a way it selects **any** element, that is the first element directly after the `#myId`. This is required, because this will be used in a program used to generate mobileconfig files, which means this will need to be used more than once. If the answer includes putting the first element after the `<key>` into a child element, the mobileconfig will be invalid.

Could this all be done in just JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure JS it's

```
<key id="myId" class="ignoreTheClass"></key>
<string>MyText</string>

<script>
    console.log(document.getElementById("myId").nextElementSibling);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery:

```
$('#myId').next()
```

I think you wanted that.

Comment: Yes, if he is using jQuery (he didn't tag his question with [tag:jQuery]). Moreover he may also *simply* want to do it in CSS...